# how insert element before anchor using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function Insert_Icon() {
 var images = document.images;
 for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    if (images[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()=='a') {
         var re = new RegExp("google\.com","ig");
        if (re.test(images[i].parentNode.href)){

            alert(images[i].parentNode.href);
        }
      /*  ---need insert this element before anchor----
       var currentElement = document.createElement("img");  
      currentElement.setAttribute("class", "icone"); 
      currentElement.setAttribute("src", "images/google.png"); */ 

    }
 }
}
```

all images with hyperlink for google show my png, try insertBefore but unsuccessfully

like this

```
<img class="icone" src="images/google.png"/><a href="http://google.com" target="_self"> <img class="cover_imagem" src="cover/2.jpg"</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is not exactly the answer to your question, but you could try using css. This will not work in all browsers, however.

```
a[href^="http://google.com"]:before {
    content: url(http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/vbVck/

Using JavaScript to perform this operation in a loop will cause many redraws which can kill performance and perceived performance of your webpage. Ideally, you would use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to test if the user's browser supports these features and do the JS fallback only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying the `<img>` needs to be removed from its parent `<a>`, and inserted before that `<a>`, then do this:

```
 // parent of <a>--------v    the <img>---------v   the <a>----------v
images[i].parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore( images[i], images[i].parentNode );
```

This invokes `insertBefore` on the parentNode of the `<a>` (that is the parentNode of the `<img>`) and inserts the `<img>` before the `<a>`.

Comment: approximately, `images[i].parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore( currentElement, images[i].parentNode);` cause infinite loop, but thanks comment.

Comment: @joelson: It doesn't cause an infinite loop for me. You'll need to post all the relevant code that reproduces your issue if you need further help.