# Add DOM elements to beginning of parent

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following javascript working to insert AJAX responses into a div with id `results`:

`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`

However, this adds all new elements after those already present. I need for the new elements to be inserted before everything else.

I know this is probably very trivial but I can't seem to find anyway to do it myself.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, it doesn't. It replaces them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how insert element before anchor using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415819/how-insert-element-before-anchor-using-javascript)

Comment: right now, every AJAX response is added to the div.

Comment: And a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814564/inserting-html-elements-with-javascript

Comment: please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+before+javascript helped answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember the exact syntax, but it something like:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("results").childNodes.addAt(0,newDiv);
```

if you can use jQuery, it's just simple as:

```
$("#results").prepend(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: "Property 'addAt' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Node & ChildNode>'."

Comment: You probably shouldn't add an answer when you don't know the correct syntax

Comment: childNodes is a read-only property, you can not add elements to it

Answer (score 17):

With modern js you can utilize the [`prepend` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend). Currently [caniuse.com says only of IE, Edge, and OperaMini are not supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=prepend).

```
ParentNode.prepend(nodesToPrepend);
```

e.g.,

```
ParentNode.prepend(newDiv);
```

Also, it automatically converts text into a text node so you could do the following for your use case:

```
document.getElementById("results").prepend(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 4):

You want either this

```
results.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforebegin', xmlhttp.responseText );
```

or this

```
results.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', xmlhttp.responseText );
```

(the variable `results` of course being a reference to the DOM element)

So, the first one will insert the new content *before* the element itself (as a previous sibling), and the second one will insert it *inside* the element before any other children).

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring the issue on clear JS so here is an example how do I fix the issue with simple node manipulation. It can be correct approach same as not. There is two options both working.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById('input-number');
const history = document.getElementById('history');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');

function getUserInput(){
  return parseInt(userInput.value);
}

function add(){
  let userInsert = getUserInput();
  let elementToAdd = document.createElement("p");
  elementToAdd.textContent = userInsert;
  /* option one */
  //if (history.hasChildNodes()){
  //  history.insertBefore(elementToAdd, history.firstChild);
  //} else {
  //  history.appendChild(elementToAdd);
  //}
  /* option two */
  history.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<p>${elementToAdd.textContent}</p>`);
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', add);
```

```css
#history {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 40rem;
  max-width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #023d6d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #023d6d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Basics</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Add History</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-11">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="input-number" placeholder="Enter content here"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="content-container">
          <section id="history"></section>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```